# Identifying names and places in literature

Tags: algorithm

I have been playing around with Markov Chain Text Generation and Naive Bayes classifiers. I am wondering if there is a way to apply either of those concepts towards identifying certain types of words in a novel. E.G. Last names or place names

I can look through my markov chain and I see that certain words tend to relate the same way to  certain other types of words. E.G. Mr. frequently comes before a last name, 'went to' tends to come before a place name and last names tend to follow first names.

Is there a good way that I can write a program that will take a list of example names and then go through a large set of books and identify all words like those names with decent accuracy? Is English regular enough for this to work? Has this been done before? Would this method have a name?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Named entity recognition comes to mind: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there are only few **patterns** for names, e.g.:

```
{FirstName}{Space}{Token with big first char}
{BigCharacter}{Dot}{Space}{Token with big first char}
{"Mr" | "Ms"}{Dot}{Space}{Token with big first char}
```

and several more. All you need is a dictionary of first names and simple engine to catch such patterns. There's a good framework for this (and many other things) - **[GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/)**. It has very large dictionary of first names and special pattern language (JAPE) for manipulating token sequences. You can use it directly or just get the dictionary and implement the logic by yourself.